# The data for trend radar

Tags: trend

Good morning,

I am a student in HTW Berlin Germany. Now I am doing my thesis about Trend Radar. This radar shows the trend for the trendy technology in this moment time or indicates the new technology in the area of health some things like that. But I got stuck that where can I get the important explicific data ?

I have found some examples on the internet :
https://opensource.zalando.com/tech-radar/,
https://global.techradar.com/de-de
But there are only the production of company

Google trend does not provide an api for the developers.

If you come up with an idea pls tell me

Thanks and stay healthy in this corona time

Comment: You said you need an API. What tool are you using?
In general you don't necessarly need API to scrap data. You can target some website and get the data you fetching the page and get the data you need via XPATH or any other tool, depending on what technology you are using for automation. For example Python have https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html 
You can use Selenium or anything like that.
Many statistical companies are using this as well as all search engine bots